# Going to a URL downloads a file but AJAX returns 403. Why and how would we resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, cors

I can't give access to company servers, but can give you an overview.

Going to a web page,   https://example.com/ATTRIBUTEDDOC001 will download a file  bar.xml

I am trying to automate some javascript, so I was doing an AJAX to https://example.com/ATTRIBUTEDDOC001 in an attempt to parse bar.xml

This page is different than what I am used to, solely for the reason that the page downloads a file.

How would I go about it?

My original attempt was:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/ATTRIBUTEDDOC001",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {Authorization: "Basic "+ encode(user+":"+pass)},
    success: function(a,b,c){alert("success"); /* ... */},
    error:   function(a,b,c){/* ... */}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and double check the CORS.  The others in my group were looking around, and it seems that the file was not set up correctly for CORS, whereas other files i was pinging DID have the permissions set up.

After this was checked, fixed, etc, i used the call again and everything was now working.

I did not have perms to look at that server data so I was hoping it was right to begin with.